# Flutter run and debug in real mobile

Tags: flutter

I want to Run flutter app on my device (HUAWEI)

when I make *flutter device*

`result:1 connected device:`

`*HUAWEI LUA L21 • WTM9K17321907973 • android-arm • Android 5.1 (API 22)*`
Note:I am using VScode

but when I make *flutter run*

`result :`

> Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for
>   information about installing additional components.

Comment: *"please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components."* - so did you do that?

Comment: true, please post flutter doctor results.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

1. flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
2. flutter doctor --android-licenses

for more information follow link -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649

Happy Coding :)